Passing formData to child component UploadModal component
I'm encountering an issue with passing formData from a parent component (CoachingService) to a child component (UploadModal) in a React application. Despite initializing formData in the parent component and passing it down to the child component, the formData received in UploadModal is blank.
"use client";
import React, { useState,useEffect } from "react";
import SearchIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Search";
import AddCircleIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AddCircle";

import CoachingCard from "./CoachingCard";
import Input from "../../../../components/Input";
import UploadModal from "../../../../components/UploadModal";
import Image from "next/image";
import { Service } from "../../../../services/services.service";
type Coaching = {
  image: string;
  name: string;
  programme: string;
  duration: string;
  selection: string;
  placement: string;
  eligibility: string;
  seatsAvailable: string;
  package: string;
  infrastructure: string;
  fees: string;
  city: string;
};
const CoachingService = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [previewImages, setPreviewImages] = useState<string>("");
  const [programme, setProgramme] = useState("");
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState("");
  const [selection, setSelection] = useState("");
  const [placement, setPlacement] = useState("");
  const [eligibility, setEligibility] = useState("");
  const [seatsAvailable, setSeatsAvailable] = useState("");
  const [avePackage, setAvePackage] = useState("");
  const [infrastructure, setInfrastructure] = useState("");
  const [fees, setFees] = useState("");
  const [city, setCity] = useState("");

  const [coaching, setCoaching] = useState<Coaching[]>([]);
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    image: '',
    duration: '',
    eligibility: '',
    infrastructure: '',
    name: '',
    package: '',
    placement: '',
    programme: '',
    seatsAvailable: '',
    selection: '',
    fees: '',
    city: '',
  });


  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await Service.getCoaching();
      // console.log("Printing data of courses api call: ", response);
      // setCourse(response?.data?.courses.slice(0, 10));
      console.log(response.data.coachings)
      setCoaching(response?.data?.coachings);
      // console.log("Printing setCollege: ",college);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching testimonials:", error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log("Printing setCourses:", course.slice(0, 10));
  }, [coaching]);

  const handleImageChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const files = event.target.files;
    if (files) {
      Array.from(files).forEach((file) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = () => {
          setPreviewImages(reader.result as string);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      });
      setOpenModal(true);
      event.target.value = "";
    }
  };

  const handleAddImages = () => {
    const newCoaching: Coaching = {
      image: previewImages,
      duration: duration,
      eligibility: eligibility,
      infrastructure: infrastructure,
      name: name,
      package: avePackage,
      placement: placement,
      programme: programme,
      seatsAvailable: seatsAvailable,
      selection: selection,
      fees: fees,
      city: city,
    };

    setCoaching([...coaching, newCoaching]);
    const newFormData = {
      image: previewImages,
      duration: duration,
      eligibility: eligibility,
      infrastructure: infrastructure,
      name: name,
      package: avePackage,
      placement: placement,
      programme: programme,
      seatsAvailable: seatsAvailable,
      selection: selection,
      fees: fees,
      city: city,
    };
    setFormData(newFormData);
    setPreviewImages("");
    setName("");
    setAvePackage("");
    setDuration("");
    setEligibility("");
    setInfrastructure("");
    setPlacement("");
    setProgramme("");
    setSeatsAvailable("");
    setSelection("");
    setCity("");
    setOpenModal(false);
  };

  const handleModalClose = () => {
    setPreviewImages("");
    setName("");
    setAvePackage("");
    setDuration("");
    setEligibility("");
    setInfrastructure("");
    setPlacement("");
    setProgramme("");
    setSeatsAvailable("");
    setSelection("");
    setCity("");
    setOpenModal(false);

      const newFormData = {
      image: '',
      duration: '',
      eligibility: '',
      infrastructure: '',
      name: '',
      package: '',
      placement: '',
      programme: '',
      seatsAvailable: '',
      selection: '',
      fees: '',
      city: '',
    };
    setFormData(newFormData);
  };

  const removeCoaching = (indexToRemove: number) => {
    setCoaching((prevItems) =>
      prevItems.filter((_, index) => index !== indexToRemove)
    );
  };
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col  w-full space-y-10">
      <div className="flex flex-col space-y-7 mt-20">
        <div className="relative flex justify-center items-center">
          <div className="rounded-full flex justify-center items-center right-10 md:right-44 cursor-pointer p-4 w-6 absolute h-6 bg-[#F36E54]">
            <SearchIcon sx={{ color: "white" }} />
          </div>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="outline-none rounded-full border-[1px] px-5 w-72 md:w-96 py-3 text-black border-[#E0E0E0] text-xs"
            placeholder="Search"
            //   value={searchQuery}
            //   onChange={(e) => setSearchQuery(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <UploadModal
          open={openModal}
          handleClose={handleModalClose}
          handleAdd={handleAddImages}
          formData = {formData}
        >
          <div className="flex flex-col">
            <h1>Add new  coaching</h1>
            <div className="flex flex-col mt-5">
              <label
                htmlFor="imageInput"
                className="bg-[#F8FAFB] aspect-square w-36 border-2 border-spacing-11 border-gray-200 border-dashed rounded-md flex flex-col space-y-2 justify-center items-center md:p0 cursor-pointer"
              >
                {previewImages ? (
                  <Image
                    src={previewImages}
                    alt={`Preview ${previewImages}`}
                    className="w-full h-full rounded-md"
                    width={100}
                    height={100}
                  />
                ) : (
                  <>
                    <AddCircleIcon
                      fontSize="large"
                      sx={{ color: "#BDBDBD", cursor: "pointer", fontSize: 56 }}
                    />
                    <h1 className="text-[#BDBDBD] text-sm">Add New</h1>
                  </>
                )}{" "}
              </label>
              <input
                type="file"
                accept="image/*"
                id="imageInput"
                className="hidden"
                multiple
                onChange={handleImageChange}
              />
              <div className="flex flex-col mt-4">
                <div className="flex space-x-2">
                  <Input
                    label="Name of the coaching"
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      setName(e.target.value);
                    }}
                    type="text"
                  />
                  <Input
                    label="City"
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      setCity(e.target.value);
                    }}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="flex space-x-2">
                  <Input
                    label="Programme"
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      setProgramme(e.target.value);
                    }}
                  />
                  <Input
                    label="Fees"
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      setFees(e.target.value);
                    }}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="flex space-x-2">
                  <Input
                    label="Duration"
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      setDuration(e.target.value);
                    }}
                  />
                  <Input
                    label="Accepted Exams"
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      setEligibility(e.target.value);
                    }}
                  />
                </div>

                <div className="flex space-x-2">
                  <Input
                    label="Seats available"
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      setSeatsAvailable(e.target.value);
                    }}
                  />

                  <Input
                    label="Infrastructure"
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      setInfrastructure(e.target.value);
                    }}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </UploadModal>
      </div>
      <div className="flex space-y-6 flex-col">
        {coaching.map((coachingItem) => (
          <CoachingCard
            key={coachingItem.name}
            eligibility={coachingItem.eligibility}
            fees={coachingItem.fees}
            image={coachingItem.image}
            name={coachingItem.name}
            programme={coachingItem.programme}
            location={coachingItem.city}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CoachingService;

//

"use client";

import AddCircleIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AddCircle";
import { Box, Modal } from "@mui/material";
import { useState } from "react";

type UploadModal = {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    open: boolean;
    handleClose: () => void; 
    handleAdd: () => void;
    formData: {
      image: string;
      duration: string;
      eligibility: string;
      infrastructure: string;
      name: string;
      package: string;
      placement: string;
      programme: string;
      seatsAvailable: string;
      selection: string;
      fees: string;
      city: string;
    };
  };
const UploadModal = ({ children, open, handleClose, handleAdd,formData}: UploadModal) => {
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpenModal(!openModal);
  };

  const handlePublish = () => {
    // Trigger the handleAdd function to update the parent component state with the new data
    
    handleAdd();
    console.log("FormData:", formData);

    // Send a POST request to your API with the form data
    fetch("api/endpoint", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          // console.log("FormData:", formData);
          console.log("Data submitted successfully");
          // Optionally, you can perform any additional actions here
        } else {
          console.error("Failed to submit data");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
  };



  // const handleChange = (e) => {
  //   const { name, value } = e.target;
  //   setFormData({
  //     ...formData,
  //     [name]: value,
  //   });
  // };

  const handleAddInfo = () => {
    setOpenModal(!openModal);
    handleAdd()
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        className="bg-[#F8FAFB] border-2 border-spacing-11 border-gray-200 border-dashed rounded-md flex flex-col space-y-2 justify-center items-center p-8 md:p-10 "
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        <AddCircleIcon
          fontSize="large"
          sx={{ color: "#BDBDBD", cursor: "pointer", fontSize: 56 }}
        />
        <h1 className="text-[#BDBDBD]">Add New</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="relative">
        <Modal open={open || openModal} onClose={handleClose}>
          <Box
            sx={{
              position: "absolute",
              top: "50%",
              left: "50%",
              transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
              width: {sm:400 , lg:600},
              bgcolor: "white",
              borderRadius: 2,
              outline: "none",
              padding:6,
              boxShadow: 24,
              p: 4,
            }}
          >
              <div className="flex   flex-col py-4 ">
                {children}
                <div className="flex  justify-center space-x-4 p-2 mt-2">
                  <button type="submit" className=" absolute right-36    text-white font-semibold px-4 py-[6px] rounded-md bg-[#f36e54] cursor-pointer " onClick={handlePublish}>
                    Publish 
                  </button>
                  <button  className="absolute right-4  border-2 text-[#f36e54] font-semibold px-4 py-1 rounded-md border-[#f36e54] cursor-pointer" onClick={handleClick}>
                    Cancel
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
          </Box>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UploadModal;

Despite setting formData in the CoachingService component and passing it down to UploadModal, the formData received in UploadModal is blank. I've tried logging formData in both components to debug, but it always returns an empty object.
Payload After submitting Data

{image: "", duration: "", eligibility: "", infrastructure: "", name: "", package: "", placement: "",…}

city: ""

duration: ""

eligibility: ""

fees: ""

image: ""

infrastructure: ""

name: ""

package: ""

placement: ""

programme: ""

seatsAvailable: ""

selection: ""




